# Javascript onload not working

Tags: javascript, onload

I am using an external javascript file, which I am using to store all my javascript functions in. Next I am trying to call a function from the body, using the next line of code:

```
<body onload="imageRefreshBig()">
```

The only thing that this function does is making an alert box pop up, well that's what's it supposed to do. I know this is a rather easy question but I have been banging my head against a wall trying to find a problem/fix for this issue and nothing is working.

I also include the javascript file in my head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
```

But as you probably see this isn't working. Could anyone explain what is going wrong with my syntax/thinking. The only thing I could think of is that either my document is not being loaded properly or that I have a syntax error.

Comment: any error in the browser console

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. Please post more information/code, otherwise we cannot help you. And: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Wasn't used to debug with the inbuild console in chrome! It noticed an syntax error, : instead of ;... The devil is in the details

Comment: One thing the might be missed, there is one `window.onload`, so if you have code anywhere else on your page or included JS with `window.onload=whatever`, it may override your `<body onload="...">`. Instead use `addEventListener` (if using old IE check the following for compatibility https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent)

Answer (score 23):

You can try use in javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
 alert("let's go!");
}
```

Its a good practice separate javascript of html

Comment: Some people are saying to use 'object.onload' which was not working for me, but this works! Changing object to window works....

Answer (score 9):

Try this one:

```
<body onload="imageRefreshBig();">
```

Also you might want to check Javascript console for errors (in Chrome it's under <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>).

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing wrong with include file in head. It seems you forgot to add`;`. Please try this one:

`<body onload="imageRefreshBig();">`

But as per my knowledge semicolons are optional. You can try with `;` but better debug code and see if chrome console gives any error.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `()`

```
<body onload="imageRefreshBig();">
```