# Onclick is working, but onload make problems?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
<p onclick="tmtm();" id="TextMobile" class="Text">&gt;&gt; F&uuml;r weitere Informationen klicken sie bitte mit Rechtsklick auf den jeweiligen Mitarbeiter</p>
```

and if I try it with onload it don't work, but onclick work:

```
<p onload="tmtm();" id="TextMobile" class="Text">&gt;&gt; F&uuml;r weitere Informationen klicken sie bitte mit Rechtsklick auf den jeweiligen Mitarbeiter</p>
```

Javascript:

```
function tmtm(){
document.getElementById("TextMobile").innerHTML = "F&uuml;r weitere Informationen halten sie bitte den jeweiligen Mitarbeiter gedr&uuml;ckt";}
```

I tried different things ...
For example I moved onload from

to , but it don't work too

Can anyone help me?

Comment: move onload to <body>

Comment: I did, but it is the same problem

Comment: onload is not an attribute for a paragraph tag: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp

Comment: I tried to move it to body, but it don't work too ...

Comment: cannot use onload in html.

Comment: I found the problem, thanks to all ... I wrote two time onload, but it accept only one in body

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274601/javascript-onload-not-working

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `onload` attribute on a paragraph.
If you absolutely must, you can achieve similar results by using the code below (using jQuery)

**Script:**

```
$('#foo').ready(function(){
alert('paragraph loaded');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<p id="foo">Sample Paragraph</p>
```